# "latex-rails" gem generates no output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, latex

I have a problem with "latex-rails" gem. I`m trying to make function which will generate a pdf. This is my code:

```
code = "\\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\\begin{document}
Don't forget to include examples of topicalization.
\\end{document}"
@latex_config={:command => 'xelatex',:parse_twice => true}
LatexToPdf.generate_pdf(code, @latex_config, parse_twice = true)
```

In a log file I can see that "Output written on input.pdf (1 page).", but there is no input.pdf and I have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right directory? (I have no idea in which directory the PDF would be put, though.)

Comment: I have searched the whole computer for 'input', but there is no input.pdf :(

Comment: I have changed code to this:
    code = "\\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \\begin{document}
    Test
    \\end{document}"
    @latex_config={:command => 'xelatex',:parse_twice => true}
    result = LatexToPdf.generate_pdf(code, @latex_config, parse_twice = true)
#    raise result.inspect
    File.open("testfile.pdf", "w") do |f|
      f.puts result
    end

And now it works, meaning testfile.pdf was created with text: Test

Comment: Looks good. Now wait six hours and post it as an answer (and after two days, accept it). I'll upvote it (and maybe others, too).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having an answer posted here instead of in the comments...

The **LatexToPdf.generate_pdf** method returns the pdf binary itself, which you'll need to write to a file. Here's one way to accomplish this:

```
code = "\\documentclass[12pt]{article} \\begin{document} Test \\end{document}" 
latex_config = {command: 'xelatex', parse_runs: 2} 

result = LatexToPdf.generate_pdf(code, latex_config)

f = File.new("testfile.pdf", "w")
f.write(result)
f.close
```

As you noted, the log file states that the output was written to a file; however, rails-latex writes this file to a temporary directory and destroys the directory at the end of the method (hence the need to write the returned binary content to a file yourself).